# HashMap only appending last value from a loop to the listview

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm splitting a string then append each split value to a hashmap which is then set to a SimpleListAdapter.However only the last value from
the split method is appended to the listview.
the code:

```
for (String set : splitSet)
                {  
                 key=splitSet[0];
                 value1= splitSet[1];
                 value2 = splitSet[2];
                 }
                hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmap.put( key, value1);
                hmap.put(key, value2);

              listrows = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
              listrows.add(hmap);

           //attach values to listview

           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    MainActivity.this, listrows,
                                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                            value1,value2},
                                    new int[] { R.id.value1,R.id.value2});
                            // updating listview
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the listview output should be integers of the following:

```
    value1
    value2

    value1
    value2
    .............
```

but im only getting the last value from the split result.what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop over `splitSet` and *only after that* you create the map and fill it -- with only the last value, obviously... Reformatted, your code gives:

```
for (String set : splitSet) {  
    key = splitSet[0];
    value1 = splitSet[1];
    value2 = splitSet[2];
}
hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hmap.put(key, value1);
hmap.put(key, value2);
```

whereas you probably meant:

```
hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (String set : splitSet) {  
    key = splitSet[0];
    value1 = splitSet[1];
    value2 = splitSet[2];
    hmap.put(key, value1);
    hmap.put(key, value2);
}
```

But there remains a problem: **you put both values into the same key**. `value1` is lost here. You probably do not mean this either. Maybe use `List<String>`s as values instead of `String`s? In which case the code becomes:

```
hmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> list;
for (String set : splitSet) {  
    key = splitSet[0];
    value1 = splitSet[1];
    value2 = splitSet[2];
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    hmap.put(key, list);
    list.add(value1);
    list.add(value2);
}
```

Comment: thanks.done as you've suggested,then i get a redmarker at hmap.put(key, list); stating that i change type of list to String..which if i do i won't be able to add value1 and value2 to it..

Answer (score 0):

Literally you are adding the last value to the `Hashmap` because you are adding value after the `for` loop terminates. This is leading to insertion of the last selected value in `Hashmap` Just change the curly bracket position in your for loop and create the `HashMap` object before `for` loop construct:

```
hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String set : splitSet)
{  
    key=splitSet[0];
    value1= splitSet[1];
    value2 = splitSet[2];
    //}//Comment it
    hmap.put( key, value1);
    hmap.put(key, value2);
}
```